# File system on SD card full when partitioning

Tags: partitioning, sd-card

See attached screen shot. I've got a Debian based distribution installed on an 8GB SD card with 2 partitions. 1 being a 59MB section for the bootable stuff, and the rest of it being the Linux file system. That 2nd part has a total capacity of 1.7GB and I want to extend it higher so I can write more to it, however in the other part of the screen shot you can see that it thinks I've used over 6GB.

I've tried installing trash-cli and running trash-empty, not that I would have a few GB of trash anyway. If I look at the SD card through my pc running Ubuntu while showing hidden files it still only shows 861MB of contents.

What should I do to gain back that space that it thinks I've used?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are both screenshots of the same partition?  The one on the right is a 1.7GB partition of which 1GB is used (861.1MB by files).  The one on the left is a 7.3GB partition of which 6.59GB is used.  I don't understand the relation.

Comment: Partition size and filesystem size are two different things.  Check the man pages for resize2fs.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comment by ubfan1 I solved the issue by running the following....

resize2fs /dev/root 3G

which resized that part of the file system to 3GB.